# remove space in between modifier labels in table data

Tags: html, jsp, jsf

In my html page, I have one table, for every row there are 8 labels, I want to 
display them without any space between labels  i.e., no space between labels from second label to till the last label and there should be some space for first label to second label How can I get this? I tried with

```
<m:div styleClass="padb">
<m:table  width="98%">
<m:tr>
<m:td width="250">
<h:outputLabel  for="primaryCarrier" value="Primary Carrier " />
<m:br/>
<h:outputLabel  for="primaryCarrier" value="(other than Medicare)" />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="diagnosisLabela" />
</m:td>

<m:td>
<h:outputLabel  for="modifier" value="Modifier " />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="modifier" />
</m:td>
 </m:td>

<m:td>
<h:outputLabel  for="modifier1" value="Modifier1 " />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="modifier1" />
</m:td>

<m:td>
<h:outputLabel  for="modifier2" value="Modifier2 " />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="modifier2" />
</m:td>

<m:td>
<h:outputLabel  for="modifier3" value="Modifier3 " />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="modifier3" />
</m:td>

 <m:td>
<h:outputLabel  for="modifier4" value="Modifier4" />
<m:br/>
<h:inputText onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" size="10" id="modifier4" />
</m:td>
```

need immediate assistance would appreciate your hep!!!
But its not working for me. Please tell me the solution. I edited my code. Please 
find it

Comment: remove `width="98%"` and you will have it.

Comment: It didn't work.. still seeing the space